# Loop extracting a median

Tags: vba, excel

This code does what I want per entry in the txtKB textbox:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim clipboardObj As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim wstest As Worksheet           
Dim clipboardTxt As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet6")
Set wstest = Sheets("Sheet8")    

lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        
ws1.Range("M1:A" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=txtKB    
ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select        
txtmedian = WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(12, 5, Columns(2))   
clipboardTxt = txtmedian.Text    
clipboardObj.SetText clipboardTxt   
clipboardObj.PutInClipboard    

wstest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = txtmedian
```

but I want to improve it (so that I will not need to manually input the ID in textbox txtKB criteria anymore, and automate everything with just one click of a button) to take an entry in `ws2` Column A (like an ID), look it up in `ws1` then perform the median extraction, paste the median in `wstest` then move to the next ID in `ws2` until it goes through all IDs in `ws2`.

Note: `ws2` is not yet in the code.

I need to place a loop somewhere I just don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim wb as workbook
set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws in wb.Worksheets
    ' Do what you want here
next ws
```

This will loop through all worksheets in the workbook

To work it into your code

```
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim clipboardObj As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim wstest As Worksheet           
Dim clipboardTxt As String

set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set wstest = Sheets("Sheet8")    

For Each ws in wb.Worksheets ' Loop through all sheets in workbook
    if not ws.name = wstest.name then ' Avoid sheet you're copying too (ammend as needed)
        With ws
            lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        
            .Range("M1:A" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=txtKB    
            .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
       End With   

       txtmedian = WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(12, 5, Columns(2))   
       clipboardTxt = txtmedian.Text    
       clipboardObj.SetText clipboardTxt   
       clipboardObj.PutInClipboard    
       wstest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = txtmedian 'You will need to change your code to paste into different locations I would have assumed, I'll leave that up to you though
    End if
Next ws
```

Comment: i'll have to test this on monday. not in the office. but thanks man!